# Graphics with discrete modeling: faster?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, discrete-mathematics, data-manipulation

I was wondering about 2d graphics coded with discrete data sets. To me, it seems that since computers operate in discrete sets that perhaps it would make more sense to do the same with graphics.

For example, rather than having a line represented by two vectors and having the computer sort out the pixel configuration and then have to algebraically determine things like the point on a line, why not represent a line in a discrete manner such as a 3d array with x and y coordinates and a finite length?

Does it not make more sense, would it not increase performance to have all of this data initialized so that memory is not wasted on calculating things rather than just using simple discrete operations to reference data locations? So in the case of a line, instead of finding x when y = 4, why not simply do line[3] ?

My question is: would handling data this way be faster and if so what would be the best way to optimize this type of computing?

Comment: Typically, smart programmers choose a data representation that suits the processing they need to do.

Comment: What if I want line[3.5]? We would need to expand our array to cover half steps. Now what if I wanted line[3.25]? Repeat.

Comment: I am assuming that each unit represents 1 pixel. There is therefore no in between.

Comment: And Oliver, I'm talking about the way the data is modelled. Cartesia planes for example, don't really exist in memory and I am suggestitg therefore that the formulas should be applied to discreet representations.

Comment: Often values in between pixels are needed for algorithms... I'd be very sure of your application before taking them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtually whenever physics and lines are involved (games, construction, visualization, ...) the question pops up whether a line intersects with something. With your discrete lines approach, it is likely that you get situations where two lines intersect without you realizing it, simply because they do not share a pixel. Just as an example:

```
x    x
 x  x 
  xx
  xx
 x  x
x    x
```

When you do the math, you can be dead certain that you will get a sensible answer in almost all situations, if you restrict your vision to pixels, you are doomed to make mistakes.

Also, the equation `ax + by = c` describes any 2D line up to infinity, whereas any discrete representation would require a lot of hassle to achieve the same generality.

Thirdly, if you intersect two 2D lines mathematically, you get the answer in a short, fixed amount of time. Your approach, however, requires searching, so your algorithm has a complexity that is worse than the mathematical approach.

The discrete approach simply does not pay off. Neither in terms of program complexity, nor in terms of speed.